# Android Component ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, components

A component I have created works fine if I put it in the main project and reference it from any res/layout xml, but when I put it in a project on which the main project depends, I get a ClassNotFoundException in the xml.

Whilst after compiling the interface works fine, it is a pain in the * to design an interface without seeing what I am doing because of the error. Does anyone know how to solve it?

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.widget.Tabber
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:465)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:564)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.computeLayout(Bridge.java:377)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.GraphicalLayoutEditor.computeLayout(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.GraphicalLayoutEditor.recomputeLayout(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.GraphicalLayoutEditor.activated(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1076)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:601)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.selectDefaultPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.addPages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1608)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2762)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2676)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by linking the source folders in Eclipse, if anyone knows another solutions I'd like to hear it...

Comment: Hi, I'm currently having the same problem.  I don't understand what you mean by "linking the source folders in Eclipse"...  how did you do that?

Comment: Right mouseclick properties > Build Path, there is a button 'Link Source' on the right, link that to the source of the separate component and tada :)

Comment: You have to add that project as an Android library too.

Answer (score 1):

'com.*.widget.Tabber' isn't a valid class name.  You need to spell it out fully.

Comment: Sorry, I added the * for package privacy reasons